# Резкий скачок объекта от земли

Tags: c#, unity3d

На сцене есть объект которое можно свободно драгать, и при драге объект с окружением ни как не взаимодействует (т.е. коллайдер переходить в состояние триггера). Проблема в том что если отпустить драгаемый объект внутри земли то объект очень резко перескакивает на поверх земли. Вопрос как можно сделать этот скачок плавным? для примерного представления закрепил изображения земли и объекта

[image: Примерное изображение]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Затормаживай `Rigidbody.velocity`, пока он не войдет в состояние покоя `IsSleeping`.